# How do I pass click event to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a two react bootstrap buttons within a dropdown and I am trying to understand why the onClick event is not working. The button are returned from function. I can get the event to fire if I just use Button in the main render function. I'd like to know why this is happening. Is returning the component from a function ok? Or do I need to use a class;

Code:

```
{this.state.filterDropdowns.map((value, indexNo) =>
    <Dropdown 
        className="button"
        key={`${indexNo}`}     
        >                
       <Dropdown.Toggle variant="light" size="sm">
           {value.name}
       </Dropdown.Toggle>
       <Dropdown.Menu className="custommenu">
            {value.data.result.map((input, index) =>
            <div key={`${index}`}>
                <input
                    key={`${index}`} 
                    id={input} 
                    type="checkbox" 
                    defaultChecked
                   onClick={(e) => this.clickFilterBox(e, indexNo)}
                   >
                </input>{" " + input}<br></br>
            </div> 
            )}
        <Dropdown.Divider />
            <CustomButtons 
                length={value.data.result.length} 
                index={indexNo}
                onClear={(e) => this.onClear(e)} 
                onSelect={(e) => this.onSelect(e)}
                 >
             </CustomButtons>            
         </Dropdown.Menu>
    </Dropdown>
 )}
```

Custom button function

```
const CustomButtons = function(props) {
      if (props.length < 10) {
        return(<div></div>);
      } else {
        return (
          <div >
            <div className="select-div">
              <Button 
                size="sm"
                onClick={props.onSelect}
                >
                Select
              </Button>
            </div>
            <div className="clear-div">
              <Button 
                size="sm"
                onClick={props.onClear}
                >
                Clear
              </Button>
            </div>
          </div>
          );
      } 
    }
```

Comment: you don't need to use class in this case. Could you provide onSelect and onClear methods too?

Comment: They just print "click" to console at the moment  - So I consider them irrelevant to the question.

Comment: actually the above example looks correct and it should work, need to see the entire component where CustomButtons is processed

Comment: check this ex.
https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-leaf-80n93?file=/src/App.js

Comment: The CustomButtons is within the main render function. I see that sandbox code seems to work. So maybe I do need a seperate class with a reference?

Comment: Can you update my example so that it looks like yours? if I understand you correctly, it should work anyway

Comment: sorry the code is too long to get working in sandbox

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your implementation as follows:

```
<CustomButtons 
  length={value.data.result.length} 
  index={indexNo}
  onClear={this.onClear.bind(this)} 
  onSelect={this.onSelect.bind(this)}
/>
```

Then in the function implement it like this:

```
<Button 
  size="sm"
  onClick={(e) => props.onSelect(e)}
>
  Select
</Button>
```

Comment: I've actually already tried that and it doesn't work. I'm starting to think "this" actually refers to the Dropdown that the buttons are within not the module that contains the functions.

Comment: Does it render any errors (in console) or does it just do nothing? Did you remember to .bind(this)?

Comment: Just does nothing. Where would I bind(this)?

Comment: Thanks for your help I'm going to try with a separate class for CustomButtons

Comment: Yeah sorry, can't help you if you don't show us the rest of your main component...

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested this is a solution:

Created a class for custom buttons

```
import React from 'react';
import {Button}  from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class CustomButtons extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            length: props.length,
            onClear: props.onClear,
            onSelect: props.onSelect
        }
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.length < 10) {
            return(<div></div>);
          } else {
            return (
              <div >
                <div className="select-div">
                  <Button 
                    size="sm"
                    onClick={this.state.onSelect}
                    >
                    Select
                  </Button>
                </div>
                <div className="clear-div">
                  <Button 
                    size="sm"
                    onClick={this.state.onClear}
                    >
                    Clear
                  </Button>
                </div>
              </div>
              );
          } 
    }
}
```

Then in main app component

```
<CustomButtons 
    length={value.data.result.length} 
    index={indexNo} 
    onClear={(e) => this.onClear(e)}
    onSelect={(e) => this.onSelect(e)}
 >
 </CustomButtons>
```

Comment: 1) you don't need to set props to state;
2) you don't need to use class, just fuction component

Comment: Yes I see your sandbox code works. Beats me why mine wasn't. I'm just going to roll with  it as separate class as it works. lol. Thanks for your help.